# Run multiple, expensive, single result queries and return a single row

Tags: sql-server, query

I have a lot of fairly large datasets in a MS SQL table, and I want to get a bunch of data about.

For example, let's say I have

| Name | Age | Height | Weight | Gender | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person | 23 | 186 | 79 | Male | GB |
| Person1 | 25 | 172 | 65 | Male | US |
| Person2 | 27 | 186 | 79 | Female | GB |
| Person3 | 19 | 187 | 68 | Female | GB |

And I want to go off and query to get the oldest male, the tallest male and heaviest male which were uploaded today. E.g. something like

```
select top 1 name, height from 'people' where country = 'GB' and gender = 'male' order by height desc;

select top 1 name, age from 'people' where country = 'GB' order by age desc
```

Note, I don't need to return the row, I just need to return the person and each SELECT will only return one row.

I'm currently running many, individual, SELECT statements but these are very expensive as I have to connect to the DB each time and the process the result.

So, ideally, I would like to merge the results of them all to return:

| Oldest | Tallest | Heaviest |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Person | Person | Person |

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the queries like this

```
select (select top 1 name from people where country = 'GB' and gender = 'male' order by height desc, Name) Tallest, 
       (select top 1 name from people where country = 'GB' order by age desc, Name) Oldest
```

But that query plan won't be optimized across the different queries.  Ie you won't see a single scan accumulating all the different queries; however each subquery may use a separate optimized access path and take advantage of indexes.

Comment: Ah, I might be falling foul of my simplified example. Each select query also has a where and an order by

Comment: Done, I think..